# Parse JSON from URL with PHP and JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I receive a json with data from URL (this is celery's flower plugin). Sample:

```
{
  "celery@s1": {
    "scheduled": [],
    "stats": {
      "clock": "2535550",
      "pid": 26002,
      "broker": {
        "transport_options": {},
        "login_method": "AMQPLAIN",
        "hostname": "127.0.0.1",
        "alternates": []
      },
      "prefetch_count": 8,
      "total": {
        "stone": 2602,
        "wood": 34
      }...
```

I try to parse it and make custom statistics page using PHP and JS.

Parsing with php:

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5555/api/workers';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach($json['celery@s1']['stats']['total'] as $item) {
    echo json_encode($item['wood']);
}

?>
```

And JS which gets data from php script with an update timer:

```
function getFromFile() {
    $.get("s_updater.php",function(response) {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(response)
        $("#field-1").html(response);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var period = 1000;
    getFromFile();
    var per = setInterval(function() {
        getFromFile();
    }, period);
});
```

But looks that I made a mistake somewhere and now I'm stuck. And is there maybe any better way to do this? 
All I want is to get "wood":34 from URL's json and show value on a html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json = json_decode($content, true);

 echo $json['celery@s1']['stats']['total']['wood'];
```

You don't have to use a loop or JSON to send a single value just echo it.

***JS Code***

```
function getFromFile() {
    $.get("s_updater.php",function(response) {
        console.log(response)
        $("#field-1").html(response);
    });
}
```

Comment: please post the output from `console.log` for more clear answer

Comment: sorry, i got rid of most stuff, forgot to delete comma. I edited the JSON in the question. Console.log shows: 
`SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'`.

Comment: @SamBronson you want to get a single key value pair from php server?

Comment: Thanks! And what about js side? How do I read what php provides properly in this case?

Comment: Sorry, I am still trying to figure this out. So now I get no errors, but still no data on page.

Comment: Are you sure that yu receive data from the URL. check it first

Comment: Yes, everything works. I can get json with postman/browser from http://127.0.0.1:5555/api/workers. So this is working fine I suppose. Checked the code, all links and names are ok. On a page itself I show the value from script.js using `<td id="field-1"></td>`. Script is loaded.

Comment: Yes, now it works. I don't really know what happened there, but after a cup of coffee and fresh air it finally worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR To get wood value you would need to access it by `$json['celery@s1']['stats']['total']['wood']`

When you are iterating `$json['celery@s1']['stats']['total']` you will get two `$item`s, but those items are integers, not arrays: 2602 for stone and 34 for wood. PHP should notice you about that.

To visualize it some more if you do

```
foreach($json['celery@s1']['stats']['total'] as $key => $item) {
    echo $key.': '.$item;
}
```

You would get:

> stone: 2602
>
> wood: 31

To get wood value you would simply do `$json['celery@s1']['stats']['total']['wood']` and decode it as json or output it as a number. When you echo it as number then don't do not expect json at JS side.

Comment: Thank you for your help!